# apache rewrite before authentication of location

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, http-authentication

I'm trying to configure an Apache webserver to work the following way:

```
if /specialdir/ -> no password check, no hostname check, no https redirect.
if 192.168.1.1 url -> redirect to https://hostname, do password check
if http://hostname/ -> redirect to https://hostname/, do password check
if '/' is requested -> redirect to https://hostname/entry/, do password check
```

So in summary, all URLs, except `specialdir` should always be visited via `https://hostname` with a mandatory authentication.

I'm currently using the following configure in `httpd.conf` and everything works, except that authentication occurs twice: once for the http connection and a second time for the https connection. Somehow my configuration doesn't do the redirect first.

(yes, I'm aware that using `Location` is considered to not be ideal, however, this way seems to be easier to enforce the same configuration for all urls / directories (since I only have one exception)).

```
<Location />
    ## authentication
    AuthBasicProvider file ldap
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthType Basic
    # allow alternative authentication, here "file"    
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthName "Login required"
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://xxx?sAMAccountName" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "xxx" 
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xxx
    require valid-user

    ## redirects
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    # in case /specialdir/ is requested - go there right away and
    # skip remaining checks.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/specialdir/"
    RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
    # someone trying to access the host by IP - redirect to hostname.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^hostname.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://hostname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    # https is off? redirect to https (because we are transmitting passwords)
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://hostname.com%{REQUEST_URI}
    # no directory requested - go to 'entry'.
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /entry/
</Location>


## allow unrestricted access to the following resources
<Directory /var/www/specialdir>
    # All access controls and authentication are disabled
    # in this directory
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the server config files, you could just separate the HTTP and HTTPS parts into 2 separate vhost configs (or separate them into 2 separate blocks in your httpd.conf):

- the HTTP vhost either serves `/specialdir/` or redirects to HTTPS
- the HTTPS vhost requires authentication.

So something like this in your http vhost config:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RedirectMatch ^/$ https://hostname.com/entry/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/specialdir/
RewriteRule .* https://hostname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# maybe include your directory directive here as well
<Directory /var/www/specialdir>
    # All access controls and authentication are disabled
    # in this directory
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

And the https vhost would just have all your auth stuff in it.